# Python argument types C++ signature

Tags: c++, python, types, signature

I have 2 questions, both relating to how arguments between Python and C++ mix...  I have a function in C++ which I am calling from python, and my function takes dates and strings.

Is a python `str` the same as a C++

```
class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >
```

And secondly, my function needs a date of type `class boost::gregorian::date`, does anyone know how I can give a date in python that will be read with the correct signature?

Help much appreciated!  I hope this is a fairly simple problem, I'm just not very experienced with different types of signatures (which doesn't bode well for my current experimentation into linking Python and C++)!

Comment: No, they're not the same. For starters, Python objects carry GC and type information around and store their attributes in completely different way. It may be possible to *convert* whenever such values cross the language barrier, but this depends on *how* you mix Python and C++ (Boost::Python? Using the C API?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `boost::python`, let me give you an idea of how to proceed in these cases. Rather than letting `boost::python` automatically wrap your function, you provide your own wrapping:

```
    namespace {

        void Foo_methodUsingDate( Foo* pointer, const object& dateObject )
        {
            boost::gregorian::date date = convertFromPython( dateObject );

            pointer->methodUsingDate( date );
        }
    }

    void wrap_Foo()
    {
        class_< Foo >( "Foo" )
            .def( "bar",
                & Foo::bar
                )
            .def( "foobar",
                & Foo::foobar
                )
            .def( "methodUsingDate",
                & Foo_methodUsingDate
                )
            ;
    }
```

Of course you need to provide a method that converts a `boost::python::object` into a `boost::gregorian::date` object. You have to decide how to handle this. For instance, you could assume that the parameter is a sequence of three integers, or you could allow more complex way of passing the parameters, or define a new class that wraps the gregorian date and all of its method and exposes it directly to Python.

As for your first question, when using `boost::python` `std::string`s are automatically converted to/from Python strings.

Answer (score 1):

No.  In order to call Python functions from C or C++, you have to use
the Python C API.  In the case of a C++ string, this will mean first
converting it to a Python string, using `PyString_FromStringAndSize(
cppString.data(), cppString.size() )`, and passing in the resulting
PyObject.  And if you want to call an arbitrary function, you'll have to
use `PyImport_Import` to load the module, then `PyObject_GetAttrString`
to get the function (Python functions are attributes, just like
everything else), then use `PyObject_CallObject` to call it, after
having converted all of the arguments and put them in a tuple (all via
functions in the Python C API).